# Interrupts handling in microcontroller

Tags: embedded

If all interrupts are disabled then how will i
find out whether the interrupt has been raised or not by using software.?
This was an interview question of NXP semiconductors.

Comment: You mean Qualcomm... ;)

Comment: BTW the answer can be: polling interrupt flags. Or in case of GPIOs you can simply poll the port status

Comment: Yeah Qualcomm.:-) how can we know by polling interupt flag? We can only check If its activated or not rit? Please explain

Comment: The question is not clear enough. If the interviewer means: _disabling interrupt using a GIE bit_ all enabled interrupt flags continue to works but the ISR is not called. So you can loop and "manually" test interrupt flag for each module.

Comment: NXP has various CPU architectures. (out of memory: 8051, ARMv5/6, ARMv7M/A, PPC, ColdFire (from Freescale), ARMv7A (various derivates), S05, S08, S12 and many more). Each arch has completely different interrupt handling, some archs even have different interrupt management within the arch. Qualcomm adds even more variations. So you first question should have been "which architecture/device"? Taking this all into account: how do you think we can answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

They are obviously fishing for an answer that says that you would poll the corresponding flag register. Flags in such registers are set regardless of whether or not they trigger an interrupt.

Anyone who has ever written any form of peripheral hardware driver will be able to answer this instantly, so the aim of the question is obviously to tell if the candidate has the slightest experience of microcontroller programming.